# How can I solve react-native styled-icon error

Tags: javascript, react-native, styled-components

I have a basic problem with usage of styled-icons in react-native.
Error: Invariant Violation: Invalid prop `display` of value `inline-block` supplied to `StyleSheet generated`, expected one of ["none","flex"]. StyleSheet generated: {   "display": "inline-block",   "verticalAlign"

There is a screenshot with this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg9ax.jpg)

Comment: react native doesnt have inline-block. use flex or block as the display property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`styled-icons` not compatible with react-native. You can use `react-native-vector-icons` instead of `styled-icons`.